# c++ problem with solving mathematic formula

Tags: c++, math, formula

im struggle to solve this math formula and i don't see where i made mistake. Little hint would be welcome.

```
using namespace std;
double sum, quo;
int n, i;
sum = 0;
quo = 1;
for (n = 1; n <= 5; n++) {

    sum = sum + quo;
}
for (i = 1; i <= 6; i++) {

    quo = quo * (n + i);
}
sum = sum + quo;

 cout << (sum);}
```

Answer should be 569520, but in my code is 665285

[image: Formula to count]

Comment: Are you sure about the about you get ?

Comment: A [mcve] would be a good start. As is, this code does not compile.

Comment: Hint - multiplication is inside summation in the formula, but in your code they are done separately.

Comment: The formula that you've provided should give `195` as the answer. Are you sure `569520` is the correct expected output?

Comment: @AjayDabas, [it shouldn't](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Sum%5BProd%5Bn%2Bi%2C%7Bi%2C1%2C6%7D%5D%2C%7Bn%2C1%2C5%7D%5D). `569520` is the expected output.

Comment: You're right, I misinterpreted the formula. `569520` is the expected output.

Comment: The first loop is not needed, it's the same as `sum = 5;`. Regarding the mathematical expression, the sum is for the whole remainder of the expression, so the multiplication should be nested inside the summing loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's been a while since I've done this sort of maths, but I think your nesting is incorrect.

What I think the formula is saying is:

```
((1 + 1) * (1 + 2) * (1 + 3) ...)
+
((2 + 1) * (2 + 2) * (2 + 3) ...)
+
...
```

However, you're summing loop only apply to i=1. I think this is just an incorrectly placed brace.

```
for (n = 1; n <= 5; n++) {
    //The n loop should encompass the whole of the i loop
    //And you should only update sum at the end
    double quo = 1;
    for (i = 1; i <= 6; i++) {
        quo = quo * (n + i);
    }
    sum = sum + quo;
}
```

Comment: try it :D 
you have to set que = 1 after every iteration in outer loop.

Comment: Yep, I caught that when looking at your answer (which I've upvoted). That will teach me to be lazy and not run it!

Answer (score 1):

As @Yksisarvinen said,

***Hint***

Multiplication is inside summation in the formula.

***Hint 2***

You can use 2 for loop inside each others

***Stop here and try it yourself then come back to see the answer.***

**the answer :**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
using namespace std;
int main() {
int sum, quo;
int n, i;
 sum = 0;
 quo = 1;
for (n = 1; n <= 5; n++) {
    for (i = 1; i <= 6; i++) {
            quo *= (n + i);

    }
    sum+=quo;
    quo =1;
}
 cout << (sum);
}
```